# Pivot Matrix to find part number where are in same delivery

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, pivot

I try to get a Matrix for parts to find out what parts are often sold together. Maybe somebody has an idea to help me out.

The table set I have:

1. table is a list with all part numbers and contains only one column "Gin".
2. table is a consumption table and contains 2 columns "Order number" and "Gin"

The goal is a matrix at the end which contains the identical article numbers in the columns and rows and shows which part was shipped with which and how often in a delivery. It needs to be dynamic because the part numbers can change and surely the orders will continue

This is the table GIN:

| GinNo |
| --- |
| Gin1 |
| Gin2 |
| Gin3 |
| Gin4 |

This is the table Consumption

| Order | GinNo |
| --- | --- |
| Order1 | Gin1 |
| Order1 | Gin2 |
| Order1 | Gin3 |
| Order2 | Gin3 |
| Order2 | Gin1 |
| Order3 | Gin4 |
| Order3 | Gin2 |

Expected Result

| Gin's | Gin1 | Gin2 | Gin3 | Gin4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gin1 | - | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Gin2 | 1 | - | 1 | 1 |
| Gin3 | 2 | 1 | - | 0 |
| Gin4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | - |

That's what I tried so far:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(GinNo)    from GIN
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query ='
SELECT  *  into test_result
FROM    (
          SELECT  P.Ginno
                  
                  , 1 AS Amount
                 
          FROM    Consumption AS T  
           JOIN GIN AS P ON  T.GinNo = P.GinNo 
           
          
        ) s
PIVOT   (COUNT(Amount) FOR Ginno IN ('+@cols+')) pvt'
execute(@query);
```

It will have the Gin's in columns but only have one line with the Amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting challenge! I'm afraid my code is significantly longer than yours, and there are probably ways it can be made more efficient but it works. Hope you find this useful!

```sql
/* -- Sample data setup code
-- Note to OP: DO NOT execute the lines in this code comment
-- in your production environment unless you want to lose
-- your tables or modify their data! For testing only.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GIN, Consumption; 

CREATE TABLE GIN (GinNo CHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE Consumption ([Order] CHAR(6), GinNo CHAR(4));

INSERT INTO GIN VALUES ('Gin1'),('Gin2'),('Gin4'),('Gin3');
INSERT INTO Consumption VALUES  ('Order1', 'Gin1'),('Order1', 'Gin2'),('Order1', 'Gin3')
,('Order2', 'Gin3'),('Order2', 'Gin1'),('Order3', 'Gin4'),('Order3', 'Gin2')
*/

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#GIN', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #GIN;
-- Add version with identity column to make it easier to loop through
CREATE TABLE #GIN (Id INT IDENTITY, GinNo VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #GIN (GinNo)
SELECT GinNo FROM GIN ORDER BY GinNo;

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @colNo INT = 1, @colName VARCHAR(50);

---- single & double quote
DECLARE @sq CHAR(1) = '''';
DECLARE @dq CHAR(2) = @sq + @sq;

WHILE @colNo <= (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM #GIN)
BEGIN
    SET @colName = (SELECT REPLACE(GinNo, @sq, @dq) FROM #GIN WHERE Id = @colNo); -- sanitise inputs
    SET @cols += CONCAT(
        ',ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN grp.GinNo2 = ''',@colName
        ,''' THEN grp.quantity END) AS VARCHAR), CASE WHEN grp.GinNo1 = '''
        ,@colName,''' THEN ''-'' ELSE ''0'' END) AS ', @colName
        ,CHAR(13) -- for better formatting when using PRINT
        );
    SET @colNo += 1;
END

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
;WITH grp
AS (
    SELECT a.GinNo AS GinNo1, b.GinNo AS GinNo2, COUNT(*) AS quantity
    FROM Consumption AS a
    JOIN Consumption AS b ON a.[Order] = b.[Order] AND a.GinNo <> b.GinNo
    GROUP BY a.GinNo, b.GinNo
    )
SELECT gin.GinNo AS [Gin''s]
' + @cols + '
FROM #GIN AS gin
LEFT JOIN grp ON gin.GinNo = grp.GinNo1
GROUP BY gin.GinNo, grp.GinNo1;';

--PRINT(@sql); -- Always review dynamic sql before execution

EXEC (@sql);

/* Re-test code after inserting more values. As expected.
INSERT INTO GIN VALUES ('Gin5')
INSERT INTO Consumption VALUES  ('Order4', 'Gin5'),('Order4', 'Gin2')
*/
```

Comment: It works exactly as expected.  It's now a challenge with 4500 parts because of limitations but i will figure that out. Many thanks

Comment: @Chris Glad it's working for you. I figured out a way to improve it in a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75251627/11418272). Same result but trimmed down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are similarities but I thought it best to write this as a new answer since it works rather differently to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197274/11418272). I found a more efficient way of achieving the same result, which does not require loops or temporary tables.

```sql
/* -- Sample data setup code
-- Note to OP: DO NOT execute the lines in this code comment
-- in your production environment unless you want to lose
-- your tables or modify their data! For testing only.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GIN, Consumption; 

CREATE TABLE GIN (GinNo CHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE Consumption ([Order] CHAR(6), GinNo CHAR(4));

INSERT INTO GIN VALUES ('Gin1'),('Gin2'),('Gin4'),('Gin3');
INSERT INTO Consumption VALUES  ('Order1', 'Gin1'),('Order1', 'Gin2'),('Order1', 'Gin3')
,('Order2', 'Gin3'),('Order2', 'Gin1'),('Order3', 'Gin4'),('Order3', 'Gin2')
*/
-- single & double quote
DECLARE @sq CHAR(1) = '''';
DECLARE @dq CHAR(2) = @sq + @sq;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
;WITH grp
AS (
    SELECT a.GinNo AS GinNo1, b.GinNo AS GinNo2, COUNT(*) AS quantity
    FROM Consumption AS a
    INNER JOIN Consumption AS b ON a.[Order] = b.[Order] AND a.GinNo <> b.GinNo
    GROUP BY a.GinNo, b.GinNo
    )
SELECT GIN.GinNo AS [Gin''s]';

SELECT @sql += CONCAT(',ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN grp.GinNo2 = ''',rGinNo,
''' THEN grp.quantity END) AS VARCHAR), CASE WHEN grp.GinNo1 = ''',rGinNo,
''' THEN ''-'' ELSE ''0'' END) AS ', rGinNo, CHAR(13))
FROM GIN
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(GinNo, @sq, @dq) AS rGinNo
) AS t
ORDER BY GinNo;

SET @sql += '
FROM GIN
LEFT JOIN grp ON GIN.GinNo = grp.GinNo1
GROUP BY GIN.GinNo, grp.GinNo1;';

--PRINT(@sql); -- Always review dynamic sql before execution
EXEC (@sql);

/* Re-test code after inserting more values. As expected.
INSERT INTO GIN VALUES ('Gin5')
INSERT INTO Consumption VALUES  ('Order4', 'Gin5'),('Order4', 'Gin2')
*/
```